# Does jQuery ajaxSetup({cache: true}) generally work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

jQuery 1.4.2 omits the **timestamp** GET parameter (to defeat browser cacheing) if I assert the ajax cache setting in the local context:

```
$.ajax({
    url: searcher, 
    data: keys,
    cache: true,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // something
    });
```

But it includes timestamp if I move the setting out of there and into the global context:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
```

Moreover, if I let the default apply, jQuery sets **timestamp**, which doesn't seem to match the manual.

Do you experience the same?

Do HTTP cache control response headers from the server affect this jQuery feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it works.
The following three ajax calls only passes a timestamp as a parameter in the 2nd case.  The name of the timestamp parameter is not **timestamp**, but rather an underscore.

```
    $.ajax({ url: '/?=testDefault',
    data: { 'cache': 'default' }
    });//no timestamp

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({ url: '/?=testFalse/',
    data: { 'cache': 'false' }
    });//yes, a timestamp

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.ajax({ url: '/?=testTrue/',
    data: { 'cache': 'true' }
    }); //no timestamp
```

As an aside, are you using an autocomplete plugin?  That passes a **timestamp** parameter by default.  You can override it using the extraParams option by passing something like this.

```
extaParams: {timestamp:'cache'}
```

Comment: It is an underscore, not a blank character.

Comment: James, I think you're right about the autocomplete plugin. That would explain the inconsistency I saw.

Answer (score -2):

You can manually add a timestamp as a get parameter, that would be a totally fine workaround right?

```
function myAjaxFunction()
{
    var tS=new Date().getTime();
    $.ajax({
        url: searcher,
        data: {timestamp:tS},
        cache: true,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //something here
        }});
}
```